# Craft CMS project.yml not syncing correctly

Tags: craftcms

I am using the latest version of Craft CMS with 'useProjectConfigFile' enabled.

My development process involves creating/updating Craft settings locally, committing this to Git and then deploying to production. The changes are then sync'd the production Craft CMS fine.

For some reason I have a Global set in the production CMS that doesn't exist on my local version.

Should this be removed when the config file is sync'd up? Any reason why it isn't not syncing correctly?

Comment: Does it recognize any differences on the production side? You can apply the changes in Craft CMS when recognized (CMS > Utilities > projectconfig).

Answer (score 1):

You could apply project config settings automatically
during deployment via the craft [console commands](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html)

```
./craft project-config/apply
```

Otherwise you have to manualiy apply the new settings in the craft control panel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to sync the configs by hand in the cp of craft cms. Then they will be applyed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try rebuilding the config with the help of this command.

> project-config/rebuild

It rebuilds the config.